# Add words received from the user to the linked-list in C programming

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char *str;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *start = NULL;
struct node *temp = NULL;
struct node *q = NULL;

void sonaEkle(char *veri) {
    struct node *eklenecek = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    eklenecek->str = veri;
    eklenecek->next = NULL;

    if (start == NULL) {
        start = eklenecek;
    } else {
        q = start;
        while (q->next != NULL) {
            q = q->next;
        }
    }
}
void yazdir() {
    q = start;
    while (q->next != NULL) {
        printf("%s", q->str);
        q = q->next;
    }
    printf("%s", q->str);
}
int main() {
    char *veri;
    while (1 == 1) {
        printf("enter string");
        scanf("%s", veri);
        sonaEkle(veri);
        yazdir();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have created a Linked list.
This linked list adds the string it received from the user to the end. But my code is giving a loop error. How can I fix this?

for example: user input:abc bcd cde

output:abc => bcd => cde

Comment: `while(1 == 1)` is an infinite loop, and also can be written as `while(1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop

```
while(1 == 1) {
    printf("enter string");
    scanf("%s",veri);
    sonaEkle(veri);
    yazdir();
}
```

Rewrite it in this way

```
while( puts("enter string") && scanf("%s",veri) == 1 ) {
    sonaEkle(veri);
    yazdir();
}
```

And also you need to allocate memory for `veri` before you can use it in scanf. But you could as well just making it an array.

```
char veri[SIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with the code

```
char *veri;
while(1 == 1){
```

1. First statement `veri` needs memory, since it is a pointer, you need some thing like this `veri = malloc(somesize);`
2. Second statement is an infinite loop, you need some termination point, better use something like below to break the infinite loop.

```
while(1){
// after malloc
scanf("%s",veri);
//enter exit whenever you want to exit from program.
if(strcmp(veri,"exit") == 0)
  break;
```

3. Function `sonaEkle` you are allocating memory for `struct node*` , but you are not returning updated nodes address `start`

you need to have `sonaEkle` like this `struct node* sonaEkle(char *veri)` and return `start` after every update and no need to cast `malloc`.

4)

```
else {
        q=start;
        while(q->next != NULL) {
            q=q->next;
        }
```

The above part just iterates list, you need to add new nodes to `q->next` when it reaches to `NULL` and return `start` afterwards in order to have next elements in the list.

Correct all those problems , to make you program work.

**NOTE:**
check the pointers for `NULL` after every `malloc`
`free` the `malloc`'ed memory once you are done with your program.